# Need help displaying a list of time in 1 hour increments

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have wrote some code that should output a list of times starting from 6:00am to 23:45pm.

I am using the DateTime class to accomplish this. The problem that I am running into, is that the while loop is an infinite  while loop. It doesn't stop.

I am having a really hard time understanding why it doesn't stop when I the condition is set to this.. \ `while ($formatted_start_time <= $end_hour){`

Anyhow I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out. Thank a lot.

Below is the code that I have so far..

```
 $start_hour = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
 $start_hour->setTime(6,00);
 $formatted_start_time = $start_hour->format("H:i:s");


    $end_hour = mktime(23,45);

 while ($formatted_start_time <= $end_hour){
    $start_hour->modify("+60 minutes");
    $formatted_start_time = $start_hour->format("H:i:s");
     echo $formatted_start_time;

 }
```

Comment: You are comparing two very different variables: `$formatted_start_time == '06:00:00'` while `$end_hour == 1408941938'` (or similar).

Comment: Ahhh. Okay. I see what you are saying. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy, and readable, using [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [`DatePeriod()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php):

```
$start_hour = new DateTime('06:00', new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
// Add one minute as the loop is NOT inclusive
$end_hour   = new DateTime('23:46', new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
$interval   = new DateInterval('PT15M');
$period     = new DatePeriod($start_hour, $interval, $end_hour);
foreach ($period as $time) {
    echo $time->format('H:i:s');
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/182802)